# Android studio - variable declarations

Tags: android-studio

Can someone tell me if it's possible to set automatic insert of 'final' modifier in Android studio(like Eclipse - Save Actions). Is it possible to find it in settings or do I need a plugin. I've tried to find this option in settings but no result. Thank you.